# How do I make KMPlayer 64X fit player window to video size on start?

Tags: kmplayer

KMP64X unlike the older "The KMPlayer" does not have screen controls that set default player window size when opening video files, which makes opening videos with different resolutions annoying as I have to manually set the window size every time I open a file. The player just keeps reverting to a default size.

Using "Remember last window size" is not really helpful as it only remembers the size of window that the last file had, so opening a 480p beforehand -> 1080p will make the player start in 480p.

Is there an option to make the player window size always fit the video resolution on start?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Playback options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYUJo.png)

Found the solution, in Playback options check the Auto Zoom in 'Default Zoom' section, set to 100% and it will adjust window size to video size / resolution upon playback.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).